# window.location.reload not working correctly on $.ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Base/SetCookie',
    data: {
        key: 'area',
        value: addrId
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(window.location); //window.location is 'localhost:12345/Cart'
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
})
```

It took me back to `localhost:12345` instead of my current page which is `localhost:12345/Cart`

Any idea what's wrong?

UPDATE :

Complete Code

```
$('.cartindexaddress').on('ifClicked', function (event) {
    var addrId = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Membership/GetUserAreaById/',
        data: {
            id: addrId
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Base/SetCookie',
                data: {
                    key: 'area',
                    value: addrId
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

tried :

```
window.location.reload(true);
location.reload();
window.location.href = window.location.href;
window.location.href = '/Cart';
window.location.href = window.location;
```

Everything is not working, still took me back to first page.

Comment: Try `window.location.href = window.location.href`

Comment: @Tushar: can you be more specific? 

I have no luck with `window.location.href = window.location.href`, still took me back to first page.

Comment: Try `document.location.reload(true);` once

Comment: What is your browser and version? It's working on Chrome

Comment: nvm I'm an idiot, the value I'm passing is not valid and I have a filter attribute which will automatically direct me back to home page if it detects non-valid value. Solved!

Comment: alert(location.href);//see url if ok use `location.reload(location.href)`

Answer (score 0):

please use $.post instead of $.ajax in my code everything is ok by using $.post

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).